# Setting shipping address in PKPaymentRequest for apple pay

Tags: ios, objective-c, applepay

Based on apple document : [PKPaymentRequest_Ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PKPaymentRequest_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/PKPaymentRequest/)

Each PKPaymentRequest has a requiredShippingAddressFields and shippingContact. I have a prepopulated shipping address. this is the address that user inserted before selecting apple pay to checkout but i want to let the user to select any other address if he wants.

this is how i make my request :

```
- (PKPaymentRequest *)paymentRequest {
    PKPaymentRequest *paymentRequest = [[PKPaymentRequest alloc] init];
    paymentRequest.merchantIdentifier = @"merchant.com.myCompany.sandbox";
    paymentRequest.requiredShippingAddressFields = (PKAddressFieldPostalAddress|PKAddressFieldPhone|PKAddressFieldName);
    paymentRequest.requiredBillingAddressFields = (PKAddressFieldPostalAddress|PKAddressFieldPhone|PKAddressFieldName);
    paymentRequest.supportedNetworks = @[PKPaymentNetworkAmex, PKPaymentNetworkVisa, PKPaymentNetworkMasterCard];
    paymentRequest.billingContact = [self contactForAddress:self.info.billingAddress];
    paymentRequest.shippingContact = [self contactForAddress:self.info.shippingAddress];
    paymentRequest.merchantCapabilities = PKMerchantCapability3DS;
    paymentRequest.countryCode = [self.info.country uppercaseString];
    paymentRequest.currencyCode = [self.info.currency uppercaseString];
    paymentRequest.paymentSummaryItems = [self summaryItems];
    paymentRequest.shippingMethods = [self shippingMethod];
    return paymentRequest;
}
```

but when apple pay window comes up, it does not show pre-set shipping contact ( what i set to paymentRequest.shippingContact ). but in document it says

> **This shipping address appears in the payment sheet**. When the
>   PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController class is presented, the user can
>   either keep the address you specified or enter a different address.

is there anything wrong in my code ?

Comment: Are you on iOS8 or 9?

Comment: I was testing on iOS 9.

Answer (score 1):

I Tried to use shippingAddress instead of shippingContact and it works.
sample code :

> https://github.com/PersianDevelopers/ApplePay-Manager